# Ntex server unreachable to cUrl from test session, but reachable from other shell...at the same time

Tags: curl, rust, rust-async-std

I am trying to test a simple ntex server.
This is the whole code inside the test:

```
use ntex::{web, web::test};
use shopp::config;

#[ntex::test]
async fn health_check_works() {
    let app = test::init_service(web::App::new().configure(config)).await;
    let req = test::TestRequest::get()
        .uri("/health_check")
        .header("content-type", "text/plain")
        .to_request();
    let resp = test::call_service(&app, req).await;
    assert!(resp.status().is_success());
}

#[ntex::test]
async fn spawn_server_works() {
    spawn_server();
    let output = std::process::Command::new("curl")
        .arg("-vvv")
        .arg("http://127.0.0.1:8000/health_check")
        .spawn()
        .expect("Failed to execute command.");
}

fn spawn_server() {
    let server = shopp::run().expect("Failed to start server.");
    let _ = async_std::task::spawn(server);
}
```

The results are all green, 2/2 working. However! The output from the verbose curl is

```
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8000...
* connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8000 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8000 after 0 ms: Couldn't connect to server
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8000 after 0 ms: Couldn't connect to server
```

But when I insert some sleep into spawn_server_works function and I start the test, I switch to another shell and I can successfully curl:

```
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8000...
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 8000 (#0)
> GET /health_check HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
> User-Agent: curl/7.88.1
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< content-length: 0
< date: Thu, 22 Feb 2024 21:02:27 GMT
< 
* Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact
```

So at the same time, curl from inside the cargo test fails, while curl from outside cargo test sessions works as expected.

Any idea?

Whole code for the server:

```
# lib.rs
use ntex::server::Server;
use ntex::web;

#[web::get("/health_check")]
async fn health_check() -> impl web::Responder {
    web::HttpResponse::Ok()
}

pub fn config(cfg: &mut web::ServiceConfig) {
    cfg.service(health_check);
}

pub fn run() -> Result<Server, std::io::Error> {
    let server = web::HttpServer::new(|| web::App::new().configure(config))
        .bind(("127.0.0.1", 8000))?
        .run();

    Ok(server)
}
```

```
# main.rs
use ntex::server::Server;
use ntex::web;

#[web::get("/health_check")]
async fn health_check() -> impl web::Responder {
    web::HttpResponse::Ok()
}

pub fn config(cfg: &mut web::ServiceConfig) {
    cfg.service(health_check);
}

pub fn run() -> Result<Server, std::io::Error> {
    let server = web::HttpServer::new(|| web::App::new().configure(config))
        .bind(("127.0.0.1", 8000))?
        .run();

    Ok(server)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: This behavior is somehow documented here https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/std_misc/process/wait.html

Apparently, std::process::Command spawns a child. This child needs to have method wait() invoked in curl case. No idea about that, nowhere in documentation. So the resulting, working code is:

```
#[ntex::test]
async fn spawn_server_works() {
    spawn_server();
    let _ = std::process::Command::new("curl")
        .arg("http://127.0.0.1:8000/health_check")
        .arg("-vvv")
        .spawn()
        .expect("Failed to execute command.")
        .wait()
        .expect("Failed to wait");
}
```

Hope that helps somebody in the future!

Comment: Just directly use [`Command::status`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html#method.status). It does essentially `.spawn().wait()` in one call.